# Background Image jQuery Isn't Working, What Am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a site that has a background image that changes every hour. I want the background image to correspond with a certain time of day. For example, an image of closed flower bud would be the site background at 12AM and an image of a blooming flower bud would be the site background at 12PM.

I am pretty sure the way I am currently implementing this is the correct way, and on inspection I don't get any errors, but the background images are not showing up. What am I doing wrong? Is it the way I'm using the jQuery or another aspect of my code? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```css
body {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

#demo {
  color: white;
}

#txt {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-size: 90px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#weather {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Blooming Time And Temperature</title>
    <link href="css/format.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
          function startTime() {
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
          moment().format("hh:mm A");
        var t = setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
        var hour = moment().hour()
      }
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

          setInterval(function(){
              var hour = new Date().getHours();
              if(hour > 7 && hour <= 12)
              {
                 // It's morning
                 $('body').css('background', 'url(http://www.magic4walls.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Macro-of-water-droplets-on-pink-lotus-flower-blooming-in-early-morning.jpg) no-repeat');
              }
              else if(hour > 12 && hour < 18)
              {
                 // It's noon
                 $('body').css('background', 'url(http://www.magic4walls.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Macro-of-water-droplets-on-pink-lotus-flower-blooming-in-early-morning.jpg) no-repeat');
              }
              else
              {
                  // It's night
                  $('body').css('background', 'url(http://www.magic4walls.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Macro-of-water-droplets-on-pink-lotus-flower-blooming-in-early-morning.jpg) no-repeat');
              }
          }, 1000 * 60 *60);

        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/3.1.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.simpleWeather({
          location: 'Brooklyn, NY',
          woeid: '',
          unit: 'f',
          success: function(weather) {
            html = '<p>'+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</p>';
            html += '<div id="city">'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</div>';

            $("#weather").html(html);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="startTime()"">
    <div id="txt"></div>
    <div id="weather"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you wait one hour to see if it works ?

Comment: Your code will work after the first hour. Try decreasing the interval time to see it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function that is provided to `setInterval` method will be invoked for the first time after time you provided (which is one hour). Change it to:

```
    function changeBackground(){
              var hour = new Date().getHours();
              if(hour > 7 && hour <= 12)
              {
                 // It's morning
                 $('body').css('background', 'url(http://www.magic4walls.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Macro-of-water-droplets-on-pink-lotus-flower-blooming-in-early-morning.jpg) no-repeat');
              }
              else if(hour > 12 && hour < 18)
              {
                 // It's noon
                 $('body').css('background', 'url(http://www.magic4walls.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Macro-of-water-droplets-on-pink-lotus-flower-blooming-in-early-morning.jpg) no-repeat');
              }
              else
              {
                  // It's night
                  $('body').css('background', 'url(http://www.magic4walls.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Macro-of-water-droplets-on-pink-lotus-flower-blooming-in-early-morning.jpg) no-repeat');
              }
          }
   changeBackground(); // invoke for the first time manually
   setInterval(changeBackground, 1000 * 60 * 60);
```

Comment: @Dekel this is why the code isn't working so it's valid as an answer

Comment: It works now! Thank you! Does this mean every time I change it I have to wait one hour to see the changes?

Comment: @AlisonDyer change interval to smaller value (like 1 minute) and conditions inside the `changeBackground` function to minutes (not hours) and check if it works. Otherwise you need to wait one hour ;) PS. if you find my answer helpful mark it as correct. thank you ;)